# recvfrom infinite receiving problem

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recv

I m writing a server using udp socket. After a client send first message to connect, i open new socket to communicate with this client on this socket (first sockets for listening) and create a thread for each client. But in thread, the while loop goes infinitely because recvfrom receive data everytime altough any client send data. What is the problem in my code?

The code sample below:

```
int main()
{

    .....

      // creating socket
 if( (sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) ) == -1 )
 {
  perror("Socket cannot be created\n");
  return FAILURE;
 }

    .....

        for(; ;)
 {

  // TAKE CLIENTS INFORMATION
  /**************************************/ 
  recvfrom(sock, &client, sizeof(Client), MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &size);  //1 

       .......

                if( (sock2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) ) == -1 )
  { 
   perror("Socket cannot be created\n");
   return FAILURE;
  }

                client.sock = sock2;

                ...

               pthread_create(thid+num_client-1, NULL, messanger, (void*)(clients + num_client-1));


        } // end of for loop
 }// end of main


// thread function
void *messanger(void *argClient)
{
     Client client = *(Client*)argClient;
     ...

     while(strcmp(message.buffer, "exit") != 0)
     { 
 recvfrom(client.sock, &message, sizeof(Message), MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &size);
 printf("%s\n", message.buffer);

     }// this file loops infinetely altough client does not send data. Printf prints onln new line

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you `bind()` the second socket (or the first, for that matter)? Why aren't you checking `recvfrom()` for failure?

This isn't the way to write a UDP server, anyway.  You use a single socket to recieve all packets.  You then inspect the sender address, match it up with the right client and handle it as appropriate (for example, you could put it onto a work queue for a per-client thread, then wake that thread up using `pthread_cond_signal()`).

Comment: hmm. i will try this. I did not satisfied with my solution also. But in tcp server, fd number that is returned from accept gets work more easy. So i can communicate with a specific client on this fd number. İ tried to pretend this way but i see it is not the way.Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

You're busy-waiting.  Try using poll or select instead.